# Preserve unicode strings in python dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to preserve the unicode in dict
here is the string looks like:

```
password = r"abc\3]xyz"
print(password)
output:
abc\3]xyz
```

But when I use the same variable in dict it's adding an escape character:

```
id_pass = { "id" : "username", "password" : password }
print(id_pass)
output:
{ u'id' : u'username', u'password' : u'abc\\3]xyz"' }

Expected:
{ u'id' : u'username', u'password' : u'abc\3]xyz"' }
```

I am not able to figure out a way.

Answer (score 2):

It's not changing the value of your string, it's merely printing its `repr()` value, which shows the escape value.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's adding an escape character because if you pass it to `repr()`, which is what is displayed, an escape character is added in the visualization. Nothing is actually being changed.

Comment: But my authentication is failing I feel when I am doing a ``json.dumps(id_pass)`` it's adding extra ``\``

Comment: ``repr()`` gives me ``\\\\``